# How to model the probability

Tags: probability

I am practicing probability before the semester starts.
I get this question which I am not sure how to solve.

> The weatherman has predicted rain tomorrow. In recent years, it has rained only
>   73 days each year. When it actually rains, the weatherman correctly forecasts rain
>   70% of the time. When it does not rain, he incorrectly forecasts rain 30% of the
>   time. What is the probability that it will rain tomorrow?

Is the 70% is the P(Rain|Correct) while the 30% is the P(Not Rain|Wrong)? Maybe I don't really get the question, but does it have something to do with the 73 days?

Any clue would be appreciated. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it rains, 70% of the time the weatherman is right. That "when" is the condition, so it's giving you P(Predicted Rain | Actual Rain).

When it doesn't rain, 30% of the time the weatherman predicts rain anyway. That "when" is still the condition, so it's giving you P(Predicted Rain | No Actual Rain).

These two alone are not enough to calculate P(Actual Rain | Predicted Rain). But there is another piece of information in the problem...

Comment: Ah so we can apply Bayes's Rule here.